# Css transition (rotate + translate) doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

I have this piece of code. It rotates the kitten image 90 degrees clockwise when I click , and rotates 90 degrees counter-clockwise when I right-click. The problem is that when I added the transition to the image, the animation when it rotated from 90 degrees to 180 degrees went in the other direction: instead of rotating 90 degrees to the right, it rotated 270 degrees to the left. That annoying transition didn't happen when I removed the translate property. Can anyone help me please?
This is the code:

```js
var deg = 0;
var $kitten = $(".kitty-spinner");
const tl = ($kitten.width() - $kitten.height()) / 2;

function rotate() {
  if (deg === -90) {
    deg = 270;
  };
  if (deg === 360) {
    deg = 0;
  }
  if (deg / 90 % 2 === 1) {
    if (deg / 90 % 4 === 1) {
      const transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)' + 'translate(' + tl + 'px, ' + tl + 'px)';
      $kitten.css({
        transform: transform
      });
    } else if (deg / 90 % 4 === 3) {
      const transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)' + 'translate(' + -tl + 'px, ' + -tl + 'px)';
      $kitten.css({
        transform: transform
      });
    }
  } else {
    const transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    $kitten.css({
      transform: transform
    });
  }
}
$kitten.contextmenu(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  deg -= 90;
  rotate();
});
$kitten.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  deg += 90;
  rotate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" class="kitty-spinner" style="transition-duration:0.5s"></img>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/skylaso1/pen/Qqpzew

Comment: why are you using const instead of vars?

Comment: Idk, maybe because I want to declare it 3 times ?

Comment: a constant is constant, a variable varies :P maybe you can add a little trick and remove the transition, reset the deg value, add a transition again and then change the transform value

Comment: I know how to do that but,I was just lazy so I copy and paste the code 3 times :P. I know that I can declare a var out of the scope and reassign it :P

Answer (score 0):

One idea, is not to do both transformation's on the image,.

Here I've created a wrapper div, that I use for translation, and leave the rotation to the image.

Also don't modulus the angle you send to the rotation, because when it gets to 270, the next is 0..  It will then just tween from 270 down-to 0, making it rotate all the way back.  Just allow the angle to keep increasing.  eg. 270, 360, 450 etc.

ps. You also need to wait for image to load before getting it's size..

```js
var deg = 0;
var $kitten = $(".kitty-spinner");
var $kittenWrapper = $(".kitty-wrapper");

let t1;

$kitten.on('load',function () {
  tl = ($kitten.width() - $kitten.height()) / 2;
});

function rotate() {
  let deg2 = deg % 360;
  let tran2 = 'translate(0px,0px)';
  if (deg2 == 90 || deg2 == 270) {
    tran2 = `translate(-${tl}px, +${tl}px`;
  }
  $kittenWrapper.css({
    transform: tran2
  });  
  const transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  $kitten.css({
    transform: transform
  });
}
$kitten.contextmenu(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  deg -= 90;
  rotate();
});
$kitten.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  deg += 90;
  rotate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kitty-wrapper" style="transition-duration:0.5s">
<img src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" class="kitty-spinner"
  style="transition-duration:0.5s"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. I haven't thought of that before. I will try to apply this to my case. :)